# how can I run maven "echo" plugin from commandline

Tags: maven

On http://mvnrepository.com I found a plugin called "echo" ( http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soebes.maven.plugins/maven-echo-plugin/0.1  ). I would like to execute it from commandline without writing anything in my pom.xml (just for fun, don't need it for anything serious). However, when I do:

```
mvn echo:echo
```

I get such error message:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'echo' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Dell Latitude E7450\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

How can I run this goal from commandline?

Comment: If you had read the [documentation](https://github.com/khmarbaise/echo-maven-plugin). Furthermore the information of mvnrepository are simply out of date you can also [search directly in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.soebes.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22echo-maven-plugin%22) for this plugin or in general via: https://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that maven can't find plugin `echo`, it tries to find this plugin in plugin groups `[org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]` and repos `[local (C:\Users\Dell Latitude E7450\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]` but failed, because its plugin group is `com.soebes.maven.plugins`. [this official doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) has very detailed information about how maven maps a prefix to a plugin.

In order to let maven be able to find it, you can add the following line to `<pluginGroups>` in your `settings.xml`:

```
<pluginGroup>com.soebes.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
```

But it'll still failed to run `mvn echo:echo` because this plugin need parameter `echos` to be configured. You can refer to [their guide](https://github.com/khmarbaise/echo-maven-plugin) for more details. An example configuration to your pom.xml to make it run:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>echo</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
 <configuration>
     <echos>
       <echo>This is the Text which will be printed out.</echo>
     </echos>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```